# create dataframe based on other column's string

Tags: python, regex, pandas

I want to create few columns based on one column condition (key word).

Here is the snippet of my DataFrame

```
Index  wave_path

0      wav48/p225/p225_001.wav
.      wav48/p227/p227_005.wav.
5
.      ......................
.      ......................

44040  wav48/p376/p376_265.wav
```

Now I have a text file with few columns depending on the ID (which is 225, 227, 376...etc). This text file has following text.

```
ID  AGE  GENDER  ACCENTS    REGION  
225  23  F       English    Southern  England
226  22  M       English    Surrey
227  38  M       English    Cumbria
228  22  F       English    Southern  England
229  23  F       English    Southern  England
230  22  F       English    Stockton-on-tees
```

I want to have these 5 columns an their respective entries based on the key word ID matching to `wave_path` columns.

```py
from pandas import DataFrame

df.loc[df.wave_path == wav48/p225/p225_001.wav, 'AGE'] = '23' 
df.loc[df.wave_path == wav48/p225/p227_005.wav, 'AGE'] = '38' 

print (df)
```

However, this will lead to hundreds lines of code and is also very time consuming. Is there any way we can do this?

Desired outcome would be:

```
Index  wave_path                      AGE    GENDER   ACCENT    REGION

0      wav48/p225/p225_001.wav        23     F        English   Southern England
.      wav48/p227/p227_005.wav.       38     M        English   Cumbria
5
.      ......................
.      ......................

44040  wav48/p376/p376_265.wav
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

first split the wave_path and fetch the ID from which is at last
`wav48/p225/p225_001.wav` --> 225

convert it into int

the use [`pd.merge()`](https://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/reference/api/pandas.DataFrame.merge.html)

```
df['ID'] = df['wave_path'].apply(lambda x :x.split("/")[-1].split("_")[0].split("p")[-1])
df['ID'] = df['ID'].astype(int)

df2['ID']  = df2['ID'].astype(int)
final_df = pd.merge(df,df2,on=['ID'],how='left')
```